# What is am I doing wrong in this IF?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

```
<td><?php if ($results['judet'] == 'Sample1') && ($results['user_id'] == 2) { echo '<a href="edit.php?id='.$results['id'].'"> Edit</a>' } elseif ($results['judet'] == 'Sample2' && ($results['user_id'] == 1) { echo '<a href="edit.php?id='.$results['id'].'">Edit2</a>' } ?></td>
```

Can anyone simply explain me why am I getting an 500 http error ?
The if checks few sql columns and if one condition is true , it shows text1 or text2 (if second condition is true).

I'm literally going nuts over this piece of code.

Comment: You closed the `if` here `($results['judet'] == 'Sample1')`

Comment: `if ($a && $b)` and not `if ($a) && ($b)`

Comment: Same with the second if, you were closer though: `elseif ($results['judet'] == 'Sample2' && (`, expand your code, don't try to write multiple lines of logic on a singular line

Comment: It'd be easier to read as just one `echo` with variable holding `2` or nothing.

Comment: Please use the `edit` option under the tags of your question, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43019806/edit. Code in comments are unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not closed the if conditions else if conditions  correctly also you missed semicolon after echo

```
   <td>
   <?php 
   if (($results['judet'] == 'Sample1') && ($results['user_id'] == 2)) { 
            echo '<a href="edit.php?id='.$results['id'].'"> Edit</a>'; 
   } elseif ($results['judet'] == 'Sample2' && $results['user_id'] == 1) { 
       echo '<a href="edit.php?id='.$results['id'].'">Edit2</a>' ;
       } ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
<?php 
if (($results['judet'] == 'Sample1') && ($results['user_id'] == 2)) {
    echo '<a href="edit.php?id='.$results['id'].'"> Edit</a>';
}elseif(($results['judet'] == 'Sample2') && ($results['user_id'] == 1)) {
    echo '<a href="edit.php?id='.$results['id'].'">Edit2</a>'; 
} ?>
</td>
```